# count all numbers from L to R such that there is exactly one zero in the binary representation.I'm very new to digit dp topic

Tags: dynamic

count all numbers from L to R such that there is exactly one zero in the binary representation.
I know that it would be F(R) - F(L-1) but not able to solve further and code it.

Comment: What programming language do you use? Have you tried something you can show us?

Comment: I use c++.So, L and R range is 10^18. What I was thinking is calculate all the numbers from 1 to R and then 1 to L-1 and subtract it like we do in digit dp. But I'm not getting how do i make the function.